# Multiple Approvers on one Document Set

Tags: 2010, workflow, document-set, approval

I'm looking to create an approval workflow on a document set which can have multiple approvers. I know how to approve one document in the set at a time or approve the entire set at once, but how can I incorporate multiple approvers in this process?

Ideally a user would mark a document as approved or reviewed and once every user has done this, the parent Document set would also be marked as approved. Any Ideas?

Comment: So you mean you want multiple approvers to approve documents in a document set? Can't that be done by selecting multiple approvers in SharePoint standard designer workflow? Or if you need different set of approvers for different document types, why don't you consider different content types for different documents and register workflows with different approvers on content types? Can you clarify a little bit?

Comment: I ended up using Nintex Workflow, Flexi Task action. Thanks for the reply though